# Resizing a cell's height and Witdth and loading an image in QTableWidget

Tags: image, qt, resize, cell, qtablewidget

I want to make a 8*8 table with square cells ( a chess board ). Now I have the code to make the table but don't know how to resize the cells to be square shaped.

I also want to put pictures of pieces into the cells. How should I do these?

here is the code i have:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTableWidget>

class Table : public QWidget
{
  public:
    Table(QWidget *parent = 0);

};


Table::Table(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);

  QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(8 , 8 , this);

  hbox->addWidget(table);
  setLayout(hbox);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Table t;

    t.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If anyone can help me with loading an image as the background of cell too, it would be very appreciated!
I use this code and compiler does not generate an error but program fails to run. I think the problem is with the `table->item(0,0)`. Should I initialize it first?

```
QString fileName = "1.bmp";
QPixmap pic (fileName);

QIcon icon (pic);

table->item(0,0)->setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Interesting approach to paint a chessboard :) I would suggest to use QGraphicsView though.

Comment: Indeed, GraphicsView would be more overhead, but would be infinitely more flexible. It would allow for animations and other fun things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the cells square shaped do something like this:

```
  // set the default size, here i've set it to 20px by 20x
  table->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(20);
  table->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(20);
  // set the resize mode to fixed, so the user cannot change the height/width
  table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
  table->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
```

**Edit:** To set the images, set the icon attribute on your [QTableWidgetItem](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtablewidgetitem.html#setIcon)s

Answer (score 1):

after searching and searching and searching.... I finally got the answer. I should first make a QBrush object and set it as a background of a QtableWidgetItem and then use table->setItem !!!

```
QString fileName = "/1.bmp";
QPixmap pic (fileName);

QBrush brush(pic);

QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setBackground(brush);

table->setItem(0,0,item);
```